# Ubuntu 20.04 not appearing in wsl.exe -l on Windows but is within Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to get Ubuntu 20.04 working with WSL2 on Windows 10 Home (10.0.19041 Build 19041) and so set the version to v2 for use with Docker Desktop.

I've set `wsl --set-default-version 2` prior to installing [Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from the Windows Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/p/ubuntu-2004-lts/9n6svws3rx71?activetab=pivot:overviewtab).

In the Ubuntu system (via Start Menu) I see:

```
$ wsl.exe -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* docker-desktop         Stopped         2
  Ubuntu-20.04           Running         1
  docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
```

However, on the Windows host in PowerShell I do not see the Ubuntu distribution:

```
> wsl -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* docker-desktop         Stopped         2
  docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
```

Why is the distro missing when running the command from the Windows host?

(Secondarily: I'm unsure why the Ubuntu is set to v1 when I've set the default install to be v2!)

Comment: Oh, by the way, that might also explain why the version was different.  If you did a `wsl --set-default-version 2` in PowerShell, that was likely also *changing* the registry settings for that Admin user.  Now that you have it running as your user, try running the `wsl --set-default-version 2` again, then either install a different distro or `wsl --export` and `wsl --import` the existing one to make sure it took effect.  Also, of course, you can change the existing one with `wsl --set-version Ubuntu-20.04 2`, although I still recommend a backup first with `wsl --export`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, as we confirmed in the comments, the problem turned out to be that PowerShell was being run in an elevated Admin session, so the `wsl -l -v` in PowerShell was retrieving (via registry entries) a different set of WSL instances that that from the (non-elevated user's) Start Menu.

For those that might run across this in the future, you can determine the Windows user for each instance and compare the two:

- In "plain" PowerShell, run `Write-Host ([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name)`
- In the WSl instance which was run from the Start Menu, run `powershell.exe -c "Write-Host ([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name)"`.  That's going to run a PowerShell subshell *within* the WSL instance to determine the user for the process.

It might also be useful to check the registry entries that WSL is using:

- PowerShell: `Get-ChildItem "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss" -Recurse`
- WSL:  `powershell.exe -c "Get-ChildItem 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss' -Recurse"`